# Pass data by pressing tab in android

Tags: java, android-intent, kotlin, tabs

I wonder how to pass data by pressing tab.  I have two tab in activity, named `Info` and `Details`. When Details tab is clicked, I want to pass the title `editText` to next activity.

[image]

**P/S : Without button clicked**

MainActivity

```
  tabs.addOnTabSelectedListener(object : TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {
            override fun onTabReselected(p0: TabLayout.Tab?) {
            }

            override fun onTabSelected(p0: TabLayout.Tab?) {
                val position = p0?.position
                when (position) {
                    0 ->
                        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(
                            R.id.frame_container,
                            CreateWOInfoFragment()
                        ).addToBackStack(null).commit()
                    else -> supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(
                        R.id.frame_container,
                        CreateWODetailsFragment()
                    ).addToBackStack(null).commit()
                }
            }

            override fun onTabUnselected(p0: TabLayout.Tab?) {
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

FragmentOne would be sending the data entered in EditText to FragmentTwo.
So add an interface in fragment one and let the activity implement this interface,
in Fragment one call the method to send data and in main fragment will handle it to send it to fragment two.

Please check this example [Android Passing Data between Fragments](https://www.journaldev.com/14207/android-passing-data-between-fragments)